# How to resize the text zone in a tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, backgrounds, box

I would like to resize the text zone in a `tcolorbox`, so that the width of the text zone is the line width but the box is larger. I tried

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[spread upwards,sharp corners=north,height=3cm,
    colframe=blue!75!black]
    This is an example for 'spread upwards'.
\end{tcolorbox}
```

and it gives me a box covering all the page, which is exactly what I want. But the text also covers all the page width....
Anyway, perhaps it is not the best way to do what I want.... I would like a colored band as a background of my text, covering all the page width. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\marginwidth}
\setlength{\marginwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\marginwidth}{-\textwidth}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{tcolorbox}[spread sidewards,left=\marginwidth/2,right=\marginwidth/2,colframe=blue!75!black]
    \lipsum[4]
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes exactly, thank you very much !